# How do I set the correct number of classLabels?

Tags: keras, artificial-intelligence, classification, coremltools

I am trying to train a neural network (classifier) with keras and convert it to coreml format. However, I am getting this error message: `The size of the output layer 'output' in the neural network does not match the number of classes in the classifier.` I double checked my training and validation datasets with: `print train_generator.class_indices
print validation_generator.class_indices`

The output is:

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 2136 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 60 images belonging to 2 classes.
{'ThumbsDown': 0, 'ThumbsUp': 1}
{'ThumbsDown': 0, 'ThumbsUp': 1}
```

This is how I convert my model:

```
ml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, input_names = 'img' ,output_names= ['output'],predicted_feature_name ='classLabel',class_labels=['thumbsDown', 'thumbsUp'], image_input_names ='img')
```

So having two class labels should be correct. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I guess you are doing binary classification and probably you have a Dense layer with **one** unit as the last layer, right? If that's the case, then the converter is confused since you have given two class labels to it. Now, if you remove the `class_labels` argument entirely, does it still work or is it a required argument?

Comment: When I remove the class_labels argument entirely it does work but I don't get a prediction. Also, you are right about the Dense layer. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I am not familiar with CoreML. I just guessed it from the error you got and the labels you have provided. There must be a supporting case for converting binary classifiers as well. I hope someone familiar with CoreML could help you.

Comment: Since you know why the error occurs, can you maybe think of a possible workaround?

Comment: You mentioned you did not get predictions. Are you sure? Nothing at all? I don't know how prediction is done in CoreML, but in Keras, as you may know, you can simply call `predict()` method and you would get the predictions. In case of a binary classifier, the prediction would be one single value between zero and one which corresponds to probability of the given sample(s) belonging to positive class (i.e. class one). So if the prediction is > 0.5 then it belongs to class one; otherwise (i.e. prediction < 0.5) it would belong to negative class (class zero). So you can manually find the label.